# how to create custom voice to be used for tts using a voice model?

Tags: windows, dll, text-to-speech, voice, sapi

Is it possible to use a voice model and then create a custom voice out of it to be used in  SpeechSynthesis api? I have a tts app using that api, and I want to add custom voices.

I already tried to add 3rd party voices such as ivona but i wana know how to they are created so that I can create one myself using the voice model that I downloaded. What I know is that I need to create the .dll for that voice but i cant find any samples. Any hint or clues will be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it’s a lot of work.  Not as much as implementing a SR engine, but not something you can just drop in.   Start here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee431802(v=vs.85)

Comment: Thanks; I am already checking the docs. What I want to find out first is the format of the voice model that I can use before I can use it for creating a custom sapi 5 voice. Any idea on how I can figure it out? I'm lost on this part

Comment: SAPI doesn't really define a 'voice model' per se.   What it implements is a well-defined interface between TTS engines and developers.   So Microsoft ships a compliant engine, Ivona ships a compliant engine, and you would implement a compliant engine.   Now, once you have an engine, you can implement a voice.   I'm not aware of TTS vendors who document their model, though.